# Sort a matrix row wise (c programming)

Tags: c, sorting, matrix

I wrote this code for sorting an nxn matrix: odd rows in descending order, double rows in ascending order, but it doesn't pass the compiler stage.

What did I do wrong?

It mostly tells me this: assignment to 'int' from 'int *' makes integer from pointer without a cast (how can I solve this problem)?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
   
int comp_a(int a, int b) {
  if (a < b) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
    
int comp_d(int a, int b) {
  if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

void sort(int a[], int n, int (*comp)(int, int)) {
  int t;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
      if (comp(a[j], a[j + 1]) == 0) {
        t = a[j];
        a[j] = a[j + 1];
        a[j + 1] = t;
      }
    }
  }
}
    
int main() {
  int n;
  printf("Enter the dimension of matrix(n): ");   
  scanf("%d", &n);                                
 
  int *mat = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    mat[i] = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
  }
    
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("Enter row [%d]: ", i);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
    }
  }
    
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i%2 == 0) {
      sort(mat[i], n, &comp_a);
    } else {
      sort(mat[i], n, &comp_d);
    }
  }
    
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems you want to allocate an array of `int*`, not `int`, so allocate that. Also it seems the comparision function should be changed or new comparision function should be created.

Comment: Showing us the compiler output that you have questions about would help. But I'm guessing it's the lines that create the matrix?

Answer (score 3):

You should change your matrix allocation to this:

```
int **mat = (int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int*)); // (1)
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    mat[i] = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));  // (2)
}
```

(1): Declaring an array of pointers of size `n` x `int*`.

(2): Where each pointer in this array points to an array of integers of size `n` x `int`.

Comment: Note: There's no need to cast the result of a calloc or malloc call, but you should always check that it isn't NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your matrix allocation

```
int *mat = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    mat[i] = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
}
```

to

```
int mat[n][n];
```

I changed for loop of ordred

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
        if(comp(a[j], a[j + 1]) == 0)
```

because he take a lot of time (time of running) to

```
 for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
        if(comp(a[i], a[j]) == 0)
```

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int comp_a(int a, int b) {
if(a < b) {
    return 1;
}
else {
    return 0;
}
}

int comp_d(int a, int b) {
if(a > b) {
    return 1;
}
else {
    return 0;
}
}

void sort(int a[], int n, int (*comp)(int, int)) {
int t;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
        if(comp(a[i], a[j]) == 0) {
            t = a[j];
            a[j] = a[i];
            a[i] = t;
        }
    }
}
}

int main() {
int n;
do
{
    printf("Enter the dimension of matrix(n): ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
}while(n<1);
int mat[n][n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("Enter row [%d]: ", i);
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(i%2 == 0) {
        sort(mat[i], n, &comp_a);
    }
    else {
        sort(mat[i], n, &comp_d);
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the best way to ask for a matrix: I did it in two ways- 1) as I wrote in this code 2)to ask from the user by index ( [0,0] [0,1]... )

and in your improvment I understand why it is better but I don't understand the while (n<1)

Comment: In your code ,you can use allocation ,because allocation method in C is used to dynamically allocate a single large block of memory with the specified size. It returns a pointer of type void which can be cast into a pointer of any form. It initializes each block with default garbage value and the size of a data structure (like Array) is changed during the runtime,so the best way to ask for a matrix is allocation method

Comment: Being able to write `int mat[n][n];` where n is not known at compile-time is a compiler extension AFAIK. ANSI C expects you to allocate and free that memory the old-fashioned way.